# non-blocking socket and io

Tags: c, sockets, io, nonblocking

my client program first connects to server,then server send a file and then client enters a command and send it to server and receives result.i want to implement this by non-blocking io for input command and non-blocking socket.
but my program can not read input from stdin.when i set only stdin in read_set it works but in this case it doesn't work.
this is my client code:

```
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int  len, rc,max_sd;
   int  sockfd;
   int on=1;
   char recv_buff[100]="";
   char command[100]="";
   char result[100]="";
   char instr_buff[100]="";
   struct sockaddr_in   addr;
   struct timeval timeout;
   fd_set read_set,write_set;

   /*************************************************/
   /* Create an AF_INET stream socket               */
   /*************************************************/
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfd < 0)
   {
      perror("socket() failed");
      exit(-1);
   }
   rc = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&on, sizeof(on)); // Allow socket descriptor to be reuseable
    if(rc<0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt() failed");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    //Set socket to be non-blocking.
    rc = ioctl(sockfd, FIONBIO, (char *)&on);
    if(rc<0)
    {
        perror("ioctl() faild");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);   
    }
   //making stdin to be non-blocking
   rc = ioctl(0, FIONBIO, (char *)&on);
   if(rc<0)
   {
        perror("ioctl() faild");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(-1);   
   } 
   /*************************************************/
   /* Initialize the socket address structure       */
   /*************************************************/
   memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
   addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   addr.sin_port        = htons(SERVER_PORT);

   /*************************************************/
   /* Connect to the server                         */
   /*************************************************/
   int count=0;

   do
   {
       rc = connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
       count++;
   }while(rc<0&&count<20);
   if(rc<0)
   {
    printf("can not connect to server\n");
    exit(-1);   
   }
   else
        printf("Connect completed.\n"); 

   timeout.tv_sec = 60;
   timeout.tv_usec = 0;
   FD_ZERO(&read_set);
   FD_ZERO(&write_set);
   FD_SET(sockfd,&read_set);
   FD_SET(0,&read_set);
   while(1)
   {   
    rc=select(sockfd+1,&read_set,&write_set,NULL,&timeout);
    if(rc<0)
    {
        perror("select failed()\n");
        break;
    }
    if(rc==0)
    {
        printf("select timed out.End Program\n");
        break;

    }
    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd,&write_set))
    {
        //sending data
        rc=send(sockfd,command,strlen(command)+1,0);
        if(rc<0)
        {
            perror("sending command failed");
            break;
        }
        if(rc==0)
        {
             printf("connection closed by server\n");
             break;
        }
        printf("command send\n");
        FD_CLR(sockfd,&write_set);

    }   
    if(FD_ISSET(sockfd,&read_set))
    {
        //receiving data
        rc=recv(sockfd,recv_buff,sizeof(recv_buff),0);
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            if(errno == EAGAIN||errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                printf("no message\n");
                continue;
            }
            perror("  recv() failed");
            break;
        }
        if(rc==0)
        {
         printf("connection closed by server\n");   
         break;   
        }
        //data received
        printf("data received\n");
        //check to see if is instr.conf or result
        if(recv_buff[strlen(recv_buff)-1]=='@') //is file
        {
         //save to instr_buff
         strcpy(instr_buff,recv_buff);   
        }
        else
        {
         //result received
         printf("Result:\n");
         printf("%s",recv_buff);   
        }
        printf("Enter Command:\n");
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(0,&read_set))
    {
        scanf("%s",command);
        FD_SET(sockfd,&write_set);
    }

   }//end of while

    close(sockfd);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `select` *updates* the read, write, and exception `fd_set` items you pass in.  This means that if you select on two possible inputs and one of them is ready, the read set has only one bit set in it:

```
/* read_set has two bits set here ... */
rc1 = select(maxfd, &read_set, ...);
/* but now read_set has only one bit set here */
rc2 = select(maxfd, &read_set, ...);
```

How many file descriptors will the second `select` call check?  With only one "ready to read", the first call cleared the bit for the other descriptor.

Note that your loop never re-initializes `read_set`.  So even though you don't have two `select` calls directly in a row, you are in effect calling `select` with some bit(s) cleared on the second and later trips through the loop.

(One typical idiom when using `select` is to have "master sets" that you use for inputs, and copy them to be modified in the call:

```
copy_reads = master_reads;
copy_writes = master_writes;
rc = select(maxfd, &copy_reads, &copy_writes, ...);
```

and then use `FD_ISSET` on &copy_reads and &copy_writes as needed.  Or, you can use `FD_ZERO` and rebuild the entire set on each trip through the loop.  Another way to bypass this issue entirely is to use `poll`, or even `epoll` or kqueues or similar.)